# Restful GET URLs for Queries, When there are multiple queries need to serve

Tags: mongodb, rest, restful-url

I have a similar structure as follows in Mongo DB for Users.

```
{ 
     "id": 112121
     "name": "Strange",
     "age": 27,
     "type": "Manager"
     "email" : "strage@gamil.com",
     "items" : [
         {
            "id": "1001",
            "name": "laptop",
            "details": [
                {
                  "attributeKey": "ManifaturedYear",
                  "attributeValue" : "2010"
                },
                {
                  "attributeKey": "EligibaleToDsipose",
                  "attributeValue" : "2018"
                }
             ]
         },
         {
            "id": "1002",
            "name": "phone",
            "details": [
                {
                  "attributeKey": "ManifaturedYear",
                  "attributeValue" : "2010"
                },
                {
                  "attributeKey": "EligibaleToDsipose",
                  "attributeValue" : "2018"
                }
             ]
         }  


      ]
}
```

I am providing a restful URIs to manipulate this resource. And has URLS as follows

CREATE

```
 POST api/users
 POST api/users/{id}/items e.g. api/user/12121/items
 POST api/users/{id}/items/{id}/details e.g. api/user/23223/items/222/details
```

UPDATE | DELETE

```
 [ PUT | DELETE ] api/users/{id}
 [ PUT | DELETE ] api/users/{id}/items/{id}
 [ PUT | DELETE ] api/users/{id}/items/{id}/details/{attributeKey}
```

My Question is How I support Get Requests

1. Get Items owned by Managers? A, B or C

> A. GET api/users/type/{type}/items e.g. GET api/users/type/Manager/items
>
> B. GET api/users/{type}/items e.g. GET api/users/Manager/items # conflicts with id
>
> C. GET api/users/items?type=Manager

2. How to get Items of user with email address abc@gmail.com

> A. GET api/users/email/abc@gamil.com/items
>
> B. GET api/users/items?userEmail=abc@gmail.com

3. How to get Items of Users who are older than 30?

Any good reference I can take to designing my rest URIs

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, if possible, would be to break out items as a top-level resource. `/users/{id}` would still have a collection of items owned by that user. Depending on your needs, you might only embed them as links, rather than full representations, in the user response. `/items` would be the canonical collection of all items. That would give you these resources:

```
/users
/users/{id}
/users/{id}/items

/items
```

If you do this, then:

1: `GET /items?ownerType=Manager`

2: `GET /items?ownerEmail=abc@example.com` (a collection of items) -or- `GET /users?email=abc@example.com` (a collection with one user)

3: `GET /items?ownerOlderThan=30`